# C++ member variable class Q_PROPERTY not available in QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am attempting to make a new QML `QQuick` object that will contain a sub-object of `QQuickPaintedItem`.

Below is a shortened portion of my c++ code

```
// PDFDocument.h //
    class PDFDocument : public QQuickItem
    {
    public:
        Q_OBJECT

        Q_PROPERTY( PDFPageView* pageView READ getPageView )

      PDFDocument( QQuickItem* parent = nullptr );
        ~PDFDocument();

      PDFPageView* getPageView() { return &m_pageView; }

      private:
        PDFPageView m_pageView;
    };

//PDFDocument.cpp//
    PDFDocument::PDFDocument( QQuickItem* parent /*= nullptr*/ )
        :QQuickItem( parent )
    {
    }

//PDFPageView.h//
    class PDFPageView : public QQuickPaintedItem
    {
    public:
        Q_OBJECT

        Q_PROPERTY( int dpi MEMBER m_dpi NOTIFY dpiChanged )

    Q_SIGNALS:
        void dpiChanged();

    public:
        PDFPageView( QQuickItem* parent = nullptr );
        ~PDFPageView();

      void paint( QPainter* painter_p );

    private:
      int m_dpi = 144;  //default dpi to 144
    };
```

Next is the actual QML snippet

```
    PDFDocument
    {
        id: pdfDocument

        anchors
        {
            fill: parent
            centerIn: parent
        }

        pageView.dpi: 200   //Invalid grouped property access
    }
```

The type is registered in the engine as well

```
qmlRegisterType<PDFDocument>( "Nordco.TechPubs", 1, 0, "PDFDocument" );
qmlRegisterType<PDFPageView>( "Nordco.TechPubs", 1, 0, "PDFPageView" );
```

For some reason I am getting an Invalid grouped property access error in the QML. I marked it with a comment in the qml code snippet.

I shortened the code because I have quite a bit, but can edit this post if i forgot to show anything. I feel like I am missing something simple here but cannot seem to get a helpful error. Any ideas?

Comment: what is your question, or what is the problem?

Comment: @folibis Sorry i should have clarified the problem with more than a comment. editing the question with...

For some reason I am getting an Invalid grouped property access error in the QML. I marked it with a comment in the qml code snippet.

Comment: does `pageView { dpi: 200 }` work?

Comment: @Amfasis unfortunately no it is the same issue

Comment: quite logically ;-) I have a working project with a same usage of grouped properties, but cannot see differences, 1 minor would that your `pageView` property is missing `CONSTANT` in you example, although maybe QQmlEngine wants it writable to become a valid candidate for grouped property access???

Comment: oh another question: do you use namespaces? You should add the full namespace in Q_PROPERTY

Comment: @Amfasis Thanks Alot! that is correct i dropped the namespaces when shortening my solution for the question. I have fixed the issue with your suggestion

Q_PROPERTY( TechnicalPublications::PDFPageView* pageView READ getPageView )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that I needed to include my namespaces when declaring a Q_Property because it is a macro. Now the custom member variable is accessable.

```
Q_PROPERTY( TechnicalPublications::PDFPageView* pageView READ getPageView )
```

Of course in shortening the problem, I excluded the namespaces my classes exist in.